# How to add a timeout to gradlew command?

Tags: java, android, tomcat, gradle, gradlew

I'm executing a .war file that i developed in Java for an Apache Tomcat server. I'm executing gradleW command with these commands:

Windows: `"cmd /c gradlew.bat assembleRelease --info"`

OS X & Linux: `"./gradlew assembleRelease --info";`

The problem is that I want to add a timeout to gradlew and I don't know how to achieve it.

It is possible?

Comment: what will the timeout do?

Comment: stop gradlew if timeout is exceeded

Comment: Why? is it not sufficient to manually kill the gradlew process using ctrl-C or ctrl-Z ?